# SQL query returning all row's values however using conditions

Tags: mysql

I don't know why but the sql query is returning all rows however I have defined the conditions as well.

When I click this link:

```
<a href="school_att.php?action=complete_attendance&c='.$s['att_class'].'&s='.$s['att_section'].'&d='.$s['att_date'].'&m='.$s['att_month'].'&y='.$s['att_year'].'">'.$student_class.$class_section.'</a>
```

It runs the following query.

The mySQL query used is:

```
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT a.*, att.*, aatt.*
    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."school_att_attendance aatt
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."school_att att ON (att.att_date=aatt.att_date)
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."student_id_card a ON (a.sid=aatt.sid)
    WHERE att.att_class = '{$mybb->input['c']}' AND att.att_section = '{$mybb->input['s']}' AND att.att_date = '{$mybb->input['d']}' AND att.att_month = '{$mybb->input['m']}' AND att.att_year = '{$mybb->input['y']}'
    ORDER BY aatt.sid ASC
");
```

and then returns all rows irrespective of the conditions used. I am sure something I am doing wrong here but I am stucked here. Please help.

[image: This is the image of the <code>main</code> table from where this query is fetching the results]

Comment: can you test the query directly ? putting the actual values and running it on a mysql client.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us a pure MySQL query, without the code tidbits?  It is hard to see what is going on here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Its complete sql query I used in my script.

Comment: I don't doubt this, but what I'm saying is that if your SQL has a logical problem, then you'd do better to actually show us that SQL, and _not_ your code.

Comment: Show the value of `$query` before execute

Comment: @farbiondriven, I used the query in the sql client and it shows the same issue

Comment: Aren't you mixing double and single quotes? I'm wondering what language would allow this `'{$mybb->input['c']}'`

Comment: @Uzma everybody is asking to show a pure query with values, without code like '{$mybb->input['c']}'. The first bit is to debug the query and if it is right then it's a code issue.